# How is the correct procedure for uninstalling or upgrading Extension Library on Domino server?

Tags: xpages

I have Extension Library instaled on Domino server 9.0.1 using update site database. Now when new version of ExtLib is released, how is the proper procedure to update to this new version? I removed  documents from update site (for existing ExtLib) and imported new ExLib version but now it seems that I have both versions on Domino when I use  `tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib`

Comment: I believe you don't have to delete the old documents.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart HTTP using `restart task http`?

FYI: XPages uses the latest version of loaded libraries.

Comment: Yes I have restarted entire server. So it means that all old versions stay in Domino but only the latest one is used?

Comment: Domino 9.0.x comes with extlib as part of the default installation. Maybe that's the old version you're seeing?

Comment: No I have Domimno 9.0.1 but I required JDBC which is not part of default R9 ExtLib so I installed OpenNtf ExtLib a month ago using update site. Now I would like to upgrade to new verions which has been just released. Here my question on how to do it properly. In update site database there is nothing like Uninstall ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete the old content from the update site, although that is a valid approach as well.

You can just disable the old content in the update site. In the image below, I have a 9.0.1 server, with 901_v00_03 of ExtLib & 901_v00_04 of ExtLib installed via update site. However, I have disabled the 901_v00_03 features in the update site (and restarted my server), and they do not show up in the console output.

[image]

The 901_v00_04 plugins show up in the console output, as do the core versions that came installed with 901 (901_v00_00_20131004-1200). The latest version of the plugins are the ones that will be used.i.e. 901_v00_04 ExtLib versions.

If you have removed the content from the active updateSite completely, and restarted the server, they should not appear in the console output at all. So we may need more info to find out what went wrong, if that is the case.